# SQL and VBScript

Tags: sql, vbscript

I want to show the quantity and Lbs purchased per customer on a web page without showing duplicate customers. The output value of total lbs is derived from retrieving the total lb in that type of package i.e. 6 for a 6 lbs per package, then in VBScript multiplying it by the quantity in that row.

```
<% Customer = ("CustomerName")
Qty = ("Qty")
ItemLbs = ("Lbs") * Qty
%>
```

It works fine without SUMing the customer names but when the duplicate customer names are SUMed the VB equation outputs incorrect information.

I would Like to corect this either via VBScript or SQL

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` and have SQL do it for you:

```
SELECT CustomerName,sum(qty*lbs) AS TotalWeight FROM yourtable GROUP BY CustomerName
```